# Is there a way to change the Powershell progress bar latter

Tags: shell, powershell, console

Power-shell provides mechanism to show progress bar using [write-progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-6)
command. Progress-bar shows using progressing 'o' char prints to the console something like this.

`oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo`

I need to change this progress-bar to show `=` char instead of `o` and final progress bar need to be something like

`==========================================================`

Is there a way to approach this?

Comment: _"Need"_ or _"want"_? I can't really see a legitimate reason to change this other than a personal preference.

Comment: Progress rendering is up to the host application, you'd need to recompile `powershell.exe` to change what you currently see (or implement your own host application)